# ParadiseInfo2 variable error code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ParadiseInfo2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   double price;
   double discount;
   double savings;
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter cutoff price for discount >>");
      price = keyboard.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Enter discount rates as a whole number >> ");
      discount = keyboard.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Special this week on any service over " +
         price);
      System.out.println("Discount of " + discount + " percent");
      System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);

   displayInfo();
   savings = computeDiscountInfo(price, discount);
   }
   public static void displayInfo()
   {
      System.out.println("Paradise Day Spa wants to pamper you.");
      System.out.println("we will make you look good.");
   }
public static double computeDiscountInfo(double pr, double dscnt)
   {
   double savings;
   savings = pr * dscnt / 100;
   return savings;

   }
}
```

I keep getting the following error on the above code.  I can't figure out how to fix it.  Thanks for all of your help!

> ParadiseInfo2.java:18: error: variable savings might not have been
>   initialized
>         System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);

Answer (score 1):

The last line of `main` sets `savings` but you use it before then to `print` it. Change it to something like

```
// System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);
displayInfo();
savings = computeDiscountInfo(price, discount);
System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);
```

Comment: Thank you! Moving that line allowed the program to run.  Appreciate your help.  I am a newbie at this.